# Redirecting page while leaving imaginary subdirectories intact

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a file, `user.php`, in the root of my my site. To access a user's page, you would visit `/user/foo-bar` where `foo-bar` is a username.

My goal is to have:

- `mysite.com/user` to redirect back to the root at `index.php`
- `mysite.com/user/foo-bar` to rewrite to `/user?name=foo-bar`.

This is what I've tried:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch   ^user/?$       /
RewriteRule     ^user/(.+)$    user?name=$1
```

but `mysite.com/user` does not redirect, nor do pages like `mysite.com/user/foo-bar` have query string data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off `MultiViews`, don't mix `RedirectMatch` with `mod_rewrite` rules and have your code like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/?$ / [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ user.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Tested, but this does not redirect `/user` to `/`. Also, on `/user/foo-bar`, `$_GET['name']` shows nothing; however, it contains the name when explicitly set: `/user/foo-bar?name=foo-bar`.

Comment: There is no `/user` directory; there is `/user.php`. Currently my `.htaccess` is what you've posted.

Comment: If `/user to /` redirection is not happening then I suspect some config issue on your side. Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: That was a problem. I've now enabled `.htaccess` but `/user/foo-bar` redirects to `/?name=foo-bar` rather than `/user?name=foo-bar`.

Comment: As per my rule `/user/foo-bar` is not redirecting. It is just rewriting without changing URL in browser. Completely clear your browser cache and then test.